# Pubnub+Python SDK on an Ubuntu Azure-hosted machine. Connection problems

Tags: android, python-3.x, azure, ubuntu-14.04, pubnub

I am experiencing a bad behavior of Pubnub in the following scenario:

1. Pubnub SDK for Python as a subscriber
2. Python 3+Django on Ubuntu 14.04
3. Ubuntu machine hosted on Azure
4. Android Pubnub client as a publisher

It seems to be that, at a certain point, the Pubnub connection on the server side becomes stale, that is, any message sent from the client is not received by the subscriber.
I have noticed that there are some errors on the log related to pubnub connection:

```
WARNING 2015-09-30 17:21:24,778 connectionpool 26551 139638563919616 Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='pubsub.pubnub.com', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=320)",)': /subscribe/.../.../0/...?uuid=...&auth=...&pnsdk=PubNub-Python/3.7.3
```

After about 5 minutes, the message is received and correctly processed.
I guess that the root of the problem lays in the way Azure manages long http connections, as:

1. The problem does not arise on my local machine, which has the very same OS version and the same stack
2. There is an obscure 'azure' parameter in the Python SDK. I tried to activate it without any noticeable difference
3. As a test I added two more subscribers on my pc and they both receive messages instaneously

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the root cause is the fact that Azure cuts HTTP connections above 4 minutes (https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/).

On the other hand, though, Pubnub creates connections with 5 minutes timeout (320 seconds, see https://github.com/pubnub/python/blob/master/pubnub.py#L1881).

Unfortunately, the Pubnub 320 seconds timeout can not be changed, whereas the Azure timeout seems to be modifiable only via Powershell scripts (uncomfortable, especially if you do not have a Microsoft Window machine).

All in all, I changed the Pubnub source code with a 120 seconds timeout and now everything is going pretty well.

It would be advisable to:

1. Document that on Pubnub side
2. Modify Pubnub so that the 320 seconds timeout can be changed
3. Improve the Azure interface in order to change the timeout parameter without using Powershell

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Most of our SDKs have the subscribe timeout parameter on init, but typically, Python is not used for subscribe so it was not provided as an option. Reviewing with engineering about that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is anything that can be done from the PubNub SDK, look at this:

### Azure flag on init

- https://github.com/pubnub/python/blob/master/pubnub.py#L2112
- https://github.com/pubnub/python/blob/master/pubnub.py#L2141-L2146

### Linux platform

And this should be getting called if Azure is running on linux: 
 - https://github.com/pubnub/python/blob/master/pubnub.py#L69-L77

Let me know if that helps any.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but it is not clear to me how to use that. I have tested the 'azure' field both with 'False' and 'True', whereas the platform is always 'linux'.